# Apache2 RewriteRule 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to rewrite my URL's and some are working but another (which is an extra directory level deep) produces a 500 internal server error. I'm not sure why this is happening and for various reasons am unable to turn on logging.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite account/order.php
RewriteRule ^account/order/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /account/order.php?order_id=$1 [L]

# Rewrite advertiser.php
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /advertiser.php?advertiser_id=$1 [L]

# Remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The URL for the rewrite rule for advertiser.php might look like this: http://domain.com/advertiser/1234

This works just fine.

However, my rewrite rule for account/order.php doesn't. It produces a 500 error. The URL might look like this: http://domain.com/account/order/1234

The only difference that I can see is that the rewrite rule has another directory in it that the working one does not. What am I missing that might cause this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to change to this both rules: RewriteRule ^account/order/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /account/order.php?order_id=$1 [R,L] RewriteRule ^account/order/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /account/order.php?order_id=$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have extra `.+` in the end of patterns. Try this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite account/order.php
RewriteRule ^account/order/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ account/order.php?order_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Rewrite advertiser.php
RewriteRule ^advertiser/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ advertiser.php?advertiser_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That fixed it. Why though? I'll admit I'm not very experienced with regular expressions so I'm not entirely sure why I had the extra ".+" at the end. However, I also see you added QSA and NC in brackets. What's the difference?